# Complex scatter chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Not sure if this is actually complex, but I can't seem to get my graph to include a legend, sourced from column D. Attached is my attempt and the data.

Essentially It looks great now, but when I add a legend, the legend appears as "series 1."

Thanks for the help in advance.
[graph attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHjUc.png)

Comment: I think you need a header for column D

Answer (score 0):

Please add a header for column D.

Then please right-click this chart > Select Data > Choose "Series 1" to edit.

[image]

Choose the cell includes the header as a Series Name.

[image]